# Move dynamic body form world using accelerometer in Box 2D

Tags: box2d, cocos2d-x

I have one dynamic body which jumps using physics in cocos2d x and I want to move dynamic body move with accelerometer use box2d and cocos2d-x.
When I move the dynamic body, then the whole world moves. I want only to move to the dynamic body.

Comment: How do you move the body? Show us some code. AFAIK using `setLinearVelocity(...)` or `applyLinearImpulse(...)` should do the trick.

Comment: In box 2d i have two body one is static and other is dynamic..dynamic fall on static body . now i want to move dynamicbody with jumping on the static body...